# Replace characters in url by regex

Tags: regex, url, redirect, replace

I'm totally new to regex,

I'm using Yoast SEO - Redirects in wordpress, How to do that?

How to Replace "-and-" by "-" in url by regex

For example:

wwww.website.com/top-products-and-brands/product1/

To:

wwww.website.com/top-products-brands/product1/

I need to know what is the regex for match  -and- 
And how to redirect to the new link?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm using Yoast SEO - Redirects in wordpress, How to do that?

Comment: Can you show more examples of URLs you want to replace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: I have never used `Yoast SEO`

I think this will work:

Regular Expression:

```
(.*)(?:-and-)(.*)
```

New Url:

```
\$1-\$2
```

But honestly, I couldn't tell you because their [docs](https://kb.yoast.com/kb/what-are-regex-redirects/) on regex don't specify the syntax they use for capture groups, (or if they even support them at all).